# Can't change the jre version in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I got an error "Syntax error, 'for each' statements are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater" in eclipse.
The jre system library being used is oracle-java-6 and I also enable project specific settings and set complier level to 1.6 but the error is still there. 
Please help, thanks ahead.

```
4. ERROR in /home/johnny/Application/GWTPV/ParaViewWeb/WebServer/PWApp/src/org/paraview/server/AvailableDataFilter.java (at line 65)
ArrayList<FileBean> tmpfileNames = new ArrayList<FileBean>();
          ^^^^^^^^
Syntax error, parameterized types are only available if source level is 1.5
```

Comment: Can't you hover over the error and change it?

Comment: Can you paste the code that is giving you the error?

Comment: But I do want to use the features provided by version higher than 1.4

Comment: @mattforsythe, it's not relayed to code rather a configuration issue. JohnyHan, have you added 1.6 library in build path?

Comment: @PradeepSimha,yes, in installed JREs, java-6-oracle is checked and under the project's properties, java-6-oracle is also shown on the Java Build Path.

Comment: @mattforsythe, code is there now

Answer (score 1):

Look at the tab "Java compiler" in your project properties. If your default jdk compilance is less than 1.5 you should check "Enable project specific settings" and edit "Compiler compilance level" to 1.5, 1.6...

Answer (score 0):

Check out the build path configuration (In the package viewer select the project root element and right mouse clic). Then check the Library setting. Often changing the JRE leaves the Library still set to 1.5.

Comment: Its one way. The other way is right-click on the project icon in the package explorer and use Build Path > Configure Build Path but its similar. Check the Library settings. There is always a JRE added maybe this version is still set to 1.5 (5.0).

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on the project -> Build Path -> Configure build path

   or 1B. Right click on project -> properties -> Java build path

   or 1C. Find the error in the Problems view, select it and click [ctrl]+[1] -> Configure build path
2. Open Libraries tab -> choose add library (or edit an exsting JRE on the list) -> JRE -> Alternate JRE -> click Installed JREs -> choose one
3. If you can't see the JRE you're looking for on the list (that is version 1.5 or greater):
   Add -> standard JVM -> in JRE home field enter the location of your JRE on the disc.